# asp.net 4 routing not working in iis 7

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, routes

I'm using asp.net 4 routing in one of our new product and it works fine in the development environment (Visual studio webserver). but when i moved it to remote iis for testing purpose it doesn't work. all i get is 404 error page. i tried adding the following to the web.config and still getting the error.

```
<system.webServer>
     <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">    
     <add name="UrlRoutingModule" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" /> 
     </modules> 
 <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
</system.webServer>
```

any ideas how to sort this issue?.

Comment: If you enable health monitoring to log to the event log (which I believe it does by default, you just have to turn it on), this catches some of those internal framework errors, and it may find something for you.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

i got the solution for this ... add the below code in ur web.config ..
 and **dont forget to add runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" in your module..**

```
   <system.webServer> 
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"> 
          <remove name="UrlRoutingModule"/> 
          <add name="UrlRoutingModule" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" /> 
        </modules> 
        <handlers> 
          <add 
            name="UrlRoutingHandler" 
            preCondition="integratedMode" 
            verb="*" path="UrlRouting.axd" 
            type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler, System.Web,  
              Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,  
              PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/> 
        </handlers> 
      </system.webServer>
```

Comment: I'm not sure that all that code is necessary, my webforms ASP.Net 4.0 app only needed runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" adding to <modules> for it to work - the other changes weren't required.

Comment: `<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"> ` is what worked for me. I spent 3 hours trying to figure this out.

Comment: @Nick - this is required on IIS7 on windows 2008 server, but it isn't required on IIS7 on windows 7 (local development)! Fun eh?

Comment: runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests will cause performance issues. Dont do it!

Answer (score 2):

Note: You have to set Application Pool to Asp.net 4.0 application pool , as routing is not working with Asp.net 4.0 Classic Application pool.