# routing not working whilst using iis instead of visual studio 2010's development server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis-7, .net-4.0

I have to deal with a legacy asp.net mvc web app (.net 4). It uses some customized routing, which works fine when I use visual studio 2010's development server. However, when I use iis instead (during debugging) it does not seem to work (never used iis during debugging before).

The answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4428278/asp-net-4-routing-not-working-in-iis-7) does not seem to help. I already use:

```
<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
</system.webServer>
```

Is there any other reason why the routing may not work? Thanks!

Comment: Have you verified that your IIS server is configured correctly?  You have to ensure that you have your application / site configured and started in IIS otherwise it won't map the domain directories correctly.

Comment: To add on to @Greg, the version of IIS is also important.

Comment: @cameronjchurch Thanks for adding that, I forgot to add that.

Comment: Thanks. I have activated it in windows 7 64bit - so it is iis 7. Btw, when I say debugging, I mean that I start the web app in vs in debug mode whilst using iis. so i do not deploy as such as far as i understand anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A generic post, unfortunately Internet Information System can create a slew of configuration issues.  This is quite possibly it's largest pitfall.  Is when you launch it on a Deployment Server, Local Server, or a Production Server the outcome may never appear to be the same.

I'll use Internet Information System Six, because it is similar to Seven and Eight but it just lacks certain features.

Inside of your project for *ASP.NET MVC Web Application* you'll want to right-click your project and select *Properties*.

You should see a tab that indicates the word: *Web**

- Inside this tab towards the bottom you'll want to ensure that *Use IIS Web Server* is selected.
- You'll want to put a *Project URL* in there.

This field should look like: `*http://localhost/ApplicationName*`.  What your essentially doing here is mapping your project directory for IIS.  You see each IIS Site stores a site inside the:

`C:\inetpub\wwwroot`

That is your Root Site Folder, where IIS will reference all of your Site Components. ** Keep in mind this Virtual Directory in projects is actually different then your IIS Configuration item listed. **

Now you'll want to open Internet Information System, you'll want to setup your *File Extensions*.  So before doing anything in IIS, you'll want to configure your *ASP.NET MVC Installer*.  You need to configure your mappings (ISAPI) to the .mvc extension to `aspnet_isapi.dll`.  This step is required in order for IIS to hand off **Routing Request using the .mvc extension to ASP.NET.**

From a good blog post he stated:

> If you’re planning to use extension-less URLs, you can skip this
>   section, but it may be useful to read anyways as it has some
>   information you’ll need to know when setting up extension-less URLs.
>   Mapping .mvc to ASP.NET
>
> If you plan to use the .mvc URL extension, and are going to deploy to
>   IIS 6 on a machine that does not have ASP.NET MVC installed, you’ll
>   need to create this mapping by performing the following steps.
>
> One nice benefit of using the .aspx extension instead of .mvc is that
>   you don’t have to worry about mapping the .aspx extension. It should
>   already be mapped assuming you have ASP.NET installed properly on the
>   machine.
>
> For the rest of you, start by right clicking on the Virtual
>   Application node (IIS6DemoWeb in this case) and select Properties. You
>   should see the following dialog.

[image: Dialog Listed]

Make sure your in the *Virtual Directory Tab* and select Configuration.  This will allow changes to the root website.  This should bring up your *Application Configuration Dialog*. That will allow you to physically map your application. Since your using `.mvc` that is what you'll select.

If `.mvc` isn't found in the list, you can point to the Data Link Library here:

`c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll`

Now before you run the application you need to update the default routes, that way they look for the proper file extension.  In your `Global.asax.cs` you'll want to ensure your using `.mvc` extension.

You would implement a method such as:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
  routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

  routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{controller}.mvc/{action}/{id}",
    new { action = "Index", id = "" }
  );

  routes.MapRoute(
    "Root",
    "",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }
  );

}
```

That should allow the site to properly display.  This is a very, very generic and broad example.  But hopefully this points you in a good direction.

---

**Update:**

When utilizing Internet Information System Seven you have to be aware of the following:

- Site Configuration
- Application Pool
- Database Configuration

Those three items are common culprits to incorrect configuration.

A really wonderful blog can be found [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/29/vs-2010-web-deployment.aspx):
Another nice article can be found [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SlowCheetahWebconfigTransformationSyntaxNowGeneralizedForAnyXMLConfigurationFile.aspx):

However, this article should hit the nail directly on the [head for you](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/deployment/using-asp-net-mvc-with-different-versions-of-iis-cs):

As I stated the above detail should resolve your issue.  But, with the introduction of IIS 7 they have two completely different methods to allow request: *Integrated* and *Classic*.

The major difference is *Integrated* will perform better and includes more features.  Where *Classic* is designed for backwards compatibility.  Your route request processing method is determined by your **Application Pool**.  With this incorrectly configured; it won't work.

1. Launch the Internet Information Services Manager
2. In the Connections window, select an application
3. In the Actions window, click the Basic Settings link to open the Edit Application dialog box
4. Take note of the Application pool selected.

> By default, IIS is configured to support two application pools:
>   DefaultAppPool and Classic .NET AppPool. If DefaultAppPool is
>   selected, then your application is running in integrated request
>   processing mode. If Classic .NET AppPool is selected, your application
>   is running in classic request processing mode.

[image: Edit Application Pool Figure 1.1]

From within that box you'll be able to modify the processing mode within an "Edit Application Dialog Box".

Hopefully this additional information better assist you for your goal. The first two blogs are a avoiding IIS, where the third one focuses specifically on IIS 7.  If you have any questions let me know.

Comment: thanks greg. i very much appreciate your lengthy answer. to be honest i would prefer to use iis 7 rather than 6. i have used 6 before plus wild card mapping during deployment but the target server use iis 7 so i would rather get this running locally with iis 7. thanks.

Comment: Well, the same information should apply.  Except IIS 7 will give you a Graphical User Interface for a bulk of it's configuration.

Comment: I added some information for IIS 7 hopefully that helps, let me know if you have anymore questions.

Comment: Thanks. Can only check tomorrow.